# Metatag aleatoria

Tags: php, javascript, html

Usamos as metatags de OpenGraph pra detalhar um pouco mais o nosso site no Facebook por exemplo.

```
<head>
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">

<meta property="og:url" content="site.com/blablabla">

<meta property="og:title" content="Título">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nome">

<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição">

<meta property="og:image" content="site.com/img.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600">

<meta property="og:type" content="website">

</head>
```

Como eu faço pra deixar os valores entre as aspas (por ex: "Nome", "Descrição") com valores diferentes a cada refresh e que o "Titulo" seja parte da url digitada, pro exemplo: site.com/nomeusuario, e assim o og:site:title seja "nomeusuario", é possível?

Comment: Já tentou usar `<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $site; ?>">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser buscar o url do site, recomendo usar `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, irá buscar o nome do site e irá apresentá-lo.

Pode chamá-lo assim, `<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">`.

Para uma melhor apresentação, recomendo substituir quaisquer `_` ou `-` com espaços vazios para melhor apresentação usando o `str_replace()`, assim ficaria o código:

```
$site_url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$site = str_replace("_"," ",$site_url);
```

E no OpenGraph ponha:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$site; ?>">
```